# How is this url formed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?'+
      'q=select%20abstract%2Cclickurl%2Cdispurl%2Ctitle%20'+
      'from%20search.web%20where%20query%3D%22'+
      $('#search').val()+
      '%22&format=json&+
      'callback=?'
```

I am just confused on this `url` on how is this formed. This `url` was `hardcoded` in my project and i was confused. Can anyone tell me how is this below url param formed?.

```
'q=select%20abstract%2Cclickurl%2Cdispurl%2Ctitle%20'+
          'from%20search.web%20where%20query%3D%22'
```

and after the search value being sent from front end, again this code appears hard-coded in url.

```
'%22&format=json&+
          'callback=?'
```

This is the form i am using in `front-end`.

```
<form action="#" id="f">
    <div>
      <label for="search">Search</label>
      <input type="text" value="kittens" id="search">
      <input type="submit" id="s" value="go">
    </div>
</form>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: It could very well have been handwritten. What about it is causing you a problem?

Comment: `'q=select%20abstract%2Cclickurl%2Cdispurl%2Ctitle%20from%20search.web%20where%20query%3D%22'` decoded = `'q=select abstract,clickurl,dispurl,title from search.web where query="'`

Comment: Use URL decoders here : http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ .. this resolves to http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select abstract,clickurl,dispurl,title from search.web where query="

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on [DecodeURLComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

decodeURIComponent('q=select%20abstract%2Cclickurl%2Cdispurl%2Ctitle%20from%20search.web%20where%20query%3D%22')

Result would be:

```
"q=select abstract,clickurl,dispurl,title from search.web where query=""
```

Generally when you pass data in querystring special characters like comma, hyphens, white spaces are encoded to make url valid address. If it contains space or and other such characters it will make url invalid. So that make sense there to write handwritten url.

Comment: What does the final param callback=? mean.

Comment: that is the address at which response will be redirected, for e.g. when you shop online you pay using some payment gateway after successful/failure of payment you are redirected to success page or error page of shopping site, that callback holds address to which response will be send

Comment: its a Callback function for JSON Data - callback - The name of the JavaScript callback function for JSONP format. If callback is set and if format=json, then the response format is JSON. "?" would mean no callback .. but please run the YQL console to confirm it

Answer (score 1):

it is an url encoded query. Decoded it looks like this:

```
select abstract,clickurl,dispurl,title from search.web where query="
```

I'd refer to the yahoo api: http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/